# Cupy arrays and scipy.stats random variables

Tags: python, scipy, cupy

I have a problem with arrays created by CuPy and using them with SciPy.Stats random variables (such as the normal continuous random variable `scipy.stats.norm`). For example, I want to evaluate the density at a point `x` under different `scale` parameters (see the code below). If I pass a numpy array to the `pdf` method, everything works well. However, if I pass a `cupy` array to the method, it always returns the following error:

```
TypeError: Implicit conversion to a NumPy array is not allowed. Please use `.get()` to construct a NumPy array explicitly.
```

May I ask why it returns this error and if there is any way to fix it?

```py
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

scale1 = np.arange(start=1, stop=11, step=1)
scale2 = cp.arange(start=1, stop=11, step=1)
rv1 = norm(loc=0, scale=scale1)
rv2 = norm(loc=0, scale=scale2)
x = 0
rv1.pdf(x)
rv2.pdf(x)
```

Comment: Right now, the only fix - if you want to use `norm` and don't want to edit SciPy source code - is to convert the array to a NumPy array first. (The normal PDF is pretty easy to write using CuPy specific functions, though; you don't need `scipy.stats` for that.) A new infrastructure that supports alternative array backends is actively in the works, though.

Comment: As to *why* it raises the error - the distribution infrastructure was written decades ago, before even NumPy existed as a separate library. In its current form, the code still relies on NumPy explicitly, and has not been converted to be more flexible about the backend because CuPy is not 100% compatible. The Python array API (https://data-apis.org/array-api/latest/) and recent work on making SciPy special function implementations accessile to other array libraries is getting us closer to what you're after.

Comment: @MattHaberland: Thank you for your reply. It looks like I have to use Numpy input for Scipy until further development of Cupy.

Comment: Not in all subpackages. Check the release notes when 1.12 comes out. There will be experimental (activated with an environment variable) array API support in a few subpackages - just not stats yet, but it is on its way.